# Add "\n" for every charachter contained in a string

Tags: regex, actionscript-3

working in AS3, in want to make vertical the text of a string. I think that the batter way is use the regular expressions, adding the "\n" for every letter contained into a string. How i can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it to a TLFText in the IDE, under its properties > Advanced > Break > "All"

Answer (score 0):

```
var myString:String = "foo bar baz"; 
// . matches every character, g makes it global
// replace with $& which is the match and add a \n at the end
myString = myString.replace(/./g, "$&\n");
```

Comment: grapefrukt, thanks
Can i ask you how to do if i want to capitalize the first letter of every WORD of the string?

Comment: @user1088417, this is really a different question, and should be asked separately . . . but, foregoing that, you should probably research regular expressions (regex, regexp).  Adobe's version is [described here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7ea9.html).